# Reference about the $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is dense in $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am a beginner of PDE, since I always see some space is dense in some space, so I want to ravel out the relation of frequently-used  space. What reference is suitable for me ?

For examples, I care about how to prove the $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is dense in $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Take $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n), \int_{R^n} \phi=1$, let $\phi_k = k^n \phi(k.)$ and $\Phi_k=1_{|x|<k}\ast \phi_k$

Send $f\in H^2(\Bbb{R}^n)$ to $g_k= f\ast \phi_k$ to make it smooth and send $g_k$ to $f_k= g_k \Phi_k$ to make it compactly supported.

Then $f_k$ approximates $g_k$ which approximates $f$.

Proof : when $f\in L^2$ then $g_k \to f$ in $L^2$ and when $\partial^a f\in L^2$ then $\partial^a g_k = \partial^a f \ast \phi_k \to \partial^a f$ in $L^2$.